# Matlab: Indoor floor plan, RF propagation

Tags: matlab, dictionary, mapping, propagation

I am new to matlab and my goal seems a little challenging for me. Hopefully I can get some directions from you guys.

Basically I have a 2D indoor office floor plan where i want to map my RF propagation model onto the map. I have seen questions in this forum on heat generation onto a map, but unfortunately it brings me no where.

i.e. [Heat map generator of a floor plan image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11805983/heat-map-generator-of-a-floor-plan-image)

A little explanation on what i wish to achieve. Firstly, on my map (with grid points) I should be able to plot some RF access points.

Secondly, on every access points I wish to map my RF propagation model. The tricky part is,  propagation is not isotropic and have many regularities that are caused by the walls on the floor plan made from different materials. My model is based on distance and received signal strength between the access points. It is very much like the image below.

[image]

Is this feasible on matlab? If yes, what are some steps or key terms i should be looking out for?

Comment: Sure - might depend on what toolboxes you have access to and how the data for your RF propagation model is stored, but in principle I don't see why you couldn't just plot some sort of filled contour and then overplot the points (+floor map if desired).

Comment: Do you already have data, or are you mapping out the process?